# Trouble with Drupal Upload Folder Permissions?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal-7, file-permissions

I have been having trouble with writing an uploaded file into a pretty vanilla Drupal 7.27 
install.

What I want to do is use tinymce and the really quite nifty file browser lioniteimages with it.  I am using the wysiwyg module though I have modified it to accept the lioniteimages package (minimally- just listing it so it works really)

Sadly, when I use lioniteimages, it fails at the upload stage, returning a 'directory is not writable' error.

Poking around in the PHP code shows this results from a FALSE flag from the PHP is_writable() call in the upload script.  I have confirmed it is checking the expected directory.  I have tried adding an is_readable call to test the same directory and this too returns FALSE so I suspect an apache issue or .htaccess here.

I have tried setting the relevant folder permissions to 755 and 777 without success.
I can upload files into the folder using cute FTP
I have tried adding .htaccess in the image upload directory:

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
```

And all without success.  It is possible to see the permissions correctly set to 777.

I get a 403 error if I try to access the /images directory in my browser with or without the .htaccess though the Drupal .htaccess removes auto directory listing.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.  Sorry there is no actual code to share - this is a configuration question really but I am stuck as to where to go from here.

The directory structure is:

```
/public_html/site/sites/all/images
/public_html/site/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/lioniteimages/connector/php
```

I have also tried deleting and re-installing the Drupal instance with only the wysiwyg module installed and the problem does not go away.  Deleting the drupal .htaccess does not help either.